# SDL2 Window Only Shows Black Background

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm starting a new project in SDL2 and as I'm still trying out different architectural approaches I usually start out by bringing up a white window to confirm that the new approach I'm trying out satisfies at least the bare minimum to get started with SDL2.

This time, I wanted to try wrapping my application into a separate `Application` class so as to unclutter `main`, like so:

```cpp
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

#include "HApplication/HApplication.h"


//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   
    HApplication application = HApplication( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );

    bool hasStarted  = application.checkRunning();
    
    
    if ( hasStarted ){

        application.run();
    
    }
    else{
        
        std::string msg = "Application failed to initialize.";
        SDL_LogError( SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_ERROR, msg.c_str() );

    }

    // add error codes
    return 0;

}
```

Now, the `run` method in `HApplication` is meant to reflect the main loop until the user exits. For test purposes, I'd just like to get two lines crossing in the middle on a white background. After initializing SDL, the window, and the renderer, which all work out fine, I'm presented with a window filled completely back, although I've used very similar code successfully before:

```cpp
void HApplication::run()
{
    // while user doesn't quit, keep going
    bool userQuit = false;

    SDL_Event e

    while( !userQuit )
    {
        // handle queued events
        while ( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
        {
            if ( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                userQuit = true;
            }
        }

        

        // clear screen
        
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( appRenderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear( appRenderer );

        // draw cross
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( appRenderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 );
        SDL_RenderDrawLine( appRenderer, 0, screenHeight/2, screenWidth, screenHeight/2);
        
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( appRenderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 );
        SDL_RenderDrawLine( appRenderer, screenWidth/2 , 0, screenWidth/2, screenHeight);
        
        // update screen with new scene 
        SDL_RenderPresent( appRenderer );
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( appWindow );
    }

    close();
}
```

I'm not quite sure why this happens, especially since I can see what I want stepping through the loop step-by-step using the debugger. I am quite honestly pretty much at a loss at where to even start.

I tried looking on Google and Stackoverflow for similar questions. However, these were mostly addressing problems with loading textures, which I haven't even gotten to yet.
If possible, I would like to keep a separate class handling game logic and resources.

EDIT: It seems like I needed to get rid of `SDL_UpdateWindow`. However, I'm not quite sure why. If anyone has an explanation, I'd be happy to hear!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SDL has both a CPU rendering API and a GPU one.

Everything that works with a `SDL_Renderer` belongs to the GPU API. For example, you can make a `SDL_Texture` and use `SDL_RenderCopy` to render it. The final step is to call `SDL_RenderPresent` so that everything that was rendered gets displayed.

`SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` is part of the CPU API. To use this API, you can for example draw to a `SDL_Surface` and then use `SDL_BlitSurface` with `SDL_GetWindowSurface` to render to the window's surface. The final step is to call `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` to display the changes, which is the equivalent to `SDL_Flip` in SDL 1.2.

In short: after the `SDL_RenderPresent` call, you get what you wanted, but after the `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` call, you overwrite that with the CPU window surface which is probably initialized to black. Just remove that `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` call and use the GPU API only.